# How to get rid of "big O" notation in this expression?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, notation, asymptotics

Let $x, y>0$ and $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to find a way to dominate (or at least get rid of the "big O" notation) the expression
$$ x^a \cdot O((xy)^b)\quad\text{ as } xy\to 0,$$
I mean I would like to say something like
$$ x^a \cdot O((xy)^b)\le c x^{a+b} y^b$$
for some positive constant $c$. Is that true? If not, how to obtain an upper bound?

The definition of big O is the one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition.

Hope someone could help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that, in your link, all $O$ statements come with an "as" phrase.  Here, you did not do that.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you, I missed it. I edit the question.

Comment: Note that, in your link, all O statements are equations [not inequalities], and the O term is on the right-hand side.  This is what the O definition provides for.  Here, yours are not like that.

Comment: @GEdgar I didn't understand your comment. Let call $z=xy$; if $f(z)=O(z^b)$ then there exists $M>0$ such that $f(z)\le M z^b$ for $z\sim 0$. Thus $x^a O(z^b)\le x^a M z^b$ for $z\sim 0$. If I am wrong, could you please show how to get rid of the $O$ notation and write equivalently the expression I asked? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much empathize with the title in your question, I'd rather get rid of all big $O$ signs all throughout mathematics. I have found them utterly confusing for years, but now that I am older and wiser I understand what was at the heart of my confusion, and from the discussion in the comments I feel that it also lies at the heart of yours. The issue is this:

**In an expression like $f(x) = O(x^a)$ the $=$-sign is not an ordinary $=$-sign of the type we use in all the rest of mathematics. It does not (I repeat: NOT) indicate equality**

- For the standard, ordinary, $=$-sign we know that whenever we have $f(x) = g(x)$, we also have $g(x) = f(x)$. Not so when we replace $g$ with some stupid big-O expression. As GE points out in the comments: the O always comes to the right of the $=$. This is because this $=$ is not an equality sign, but an impossible-to-break-off part of the whole expression "$= O(...)$"
- For the standard, ordinary, $=$ sign we have that when $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f(x) \leq cx^{a+b}y^b$ then obviously, obviously, without thinking, you can substitute the $g$ for the $f$ and conclude that $g(x) \leq cx^{a+b}y^b$ as well, as you do in your question. However when $g$ is some stupid big O this substitution process is meaningless, because the $O$-part is not *equal* to whatever is on the left in the expression $f(x) = O(...)$.

So what to do about this? I always feel it would have helped me if people would have written $f(x) \leq O(...)$ instead of $f(x) = O(...)$, but it is too late to change their minds now, I fear. Instead the best I can tell you is what I said above:

The expression "$= x^aO((xy)^b)$" should be thought of as an unbreakable whole, an expression in itself whose first character happens to look like the familiar "=" but in reality is just two lines - two of many lines and squiggles that together make up the whole thing, "$= x^aO((xy)^b)$".

This thing, taken as a whole, means "$\leq cx^{a+b}y^b$ for some $c$" (as you already correctly concluded) and thus (because of it starting with the 'verb' $\leq$) will only appear as part of a sentence like "$f(x) \leq cx^{a+b}y^b$ (or, in this dreadful notation, $f(x) = x^{a}O((xy)^b)$) and not floating around on its own.

PS sorry if this answer is overly opiniated. I still hope it is useful.

Comment: In my opinion, $O(x^a)$ is a class of functions. So it is perhaps better to understand $f(x)=O(x^a)$ as $f(x)\in O(x^a)$. (But don't write it this way! It's bad for intuitive algebraic manipulation) By the way, I empathise with using $\le$ for $O$ and only using $=$ for $\Theta$.

Comment: O yes, that is another good way of looking at it!

Comment: @Vincent thank you for the answer. So, you think my conclusion is correct, right?

Comment: "I always feel it would have helped me if people would have written $f(x) \leq O(\dots)$ instead of $f(x) = O(\dots)$"---well have I got a Vinogradov notation (i.e. $f(x) \ll \dots$) to sell you!

Comment: @C.Bishop Are you correct? Yes and no. Whenever you have a sentence like "$f(x) = x^a O((xy)^b)$ as $xy \to 0$" you can replace it by the equivalent sentence "There is a positive $c$ such that $f(x) \leq  c x^{a+b}y^b$ as $xy \to 0$". But you cannot write what you wrote, with the O on the left hand side of an inequality. Big O's never appear at the left hand side.

Comment: So on a mathematical content level you are correct about the meaning of the O-expression, but on a notational level you are not correct about how to use it. Of course this is not a problem if in the end your goal is not to use it at all...

Comment: Put a different way: the very first expression in your post would never occur on its own. It is always part of a larger expression talking about some other quantity domineered by this thing. Now in this larger expression you can replace the big O part with the nicer O-free expression that you derived without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

To 'get rid of it' you introduce the unknown function that it represents i.e. replace $x^a O((xy)^b)$ by $x^a f(x,y)$, with the additional information that $f(x,y) = O((xy)^b)$, i.e. $f(x,y) \leq C (xy)^b$